# Is there an easy way to understand what causes conda environment inconsistencies?

Tags: conda

While trying to debug `conda update -n base conda` for telling me the environment is inconsistent, I found myself hopelss facing this:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::requests==2.27.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::python==3.9.0=h4f09611_5_cpython
  - conda-forge/noarch::six==1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::charset-normalizer==2.0.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::conda==4.13.0=py39h6e9494a_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::sqlite==3.37.1=hb516253_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::urllib3==1.26.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::setuptools==63.2.0=py39h6e9494a_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::wheel==0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::python.app==1.4=py39h89e85a6_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::colorama==0.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pycosat==0.6.3=py39h63b48b0_1010
  - conda-forge/osx-64::cryptography==37.0.4=py39h9c2a9ce_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::ruamel_yaml==0.15.80=py39h701faf5_1007
  - conda-forge/noarch::pyopenssl==22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::certifi==2022.6.15=py39h6e9494a_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::idna==3.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::readline==8.1=h05e3726_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::tqdm==4.63.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::python_abi==3.9=2_cp39
  - conda-forge/osx-64::brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h63b48b0_1004
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pysocks==1.7.1=py39h6e9494a_5
  - conda-forge/osx-64::cffi==1.14.6=py39hb71fe58_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::conda-package-handling==1.8.1=py39h63b48b0_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::pip==22.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pycparser==2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
```

Is there an easy way for humans to understand what here is conflicting with what, in a way that will give some intuition as to how solve the inconsistency?

Comment: (updating the links) The documentation has [a section of *"Deep Dives"*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/23.10.x/dev-guide/deep-dives/index.html) describing in more detail the specifications of how Conda is supposed to work as well as some implementation details. In particular, [the article on *"Solvers"*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/23.10.x/dev-guide/deep-dives/solvers.html) might be relevant here.